# how to use "new" to allocate memory of the point reference argument inside a function

Tags: c++, memory, reference, point

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct ListNode {
 int val;
 ListNode *next;
 ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

void insert(ListNode *&head,int value)
{
    ListNode *node;
    node = head;
    if(!node)
    {
        //node = new ListNode(value);
        head = new ListNode(value);
    }
    else
    {
        while(node->next != NULL)
            node = node->next;
        node->next = new ListNode(value);
    }
}
void print(ListNode *head)
{
    ListNode *node = head;
    for(;node!=NULL;){
        printf("%d ",node->val);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    insert(head,0);

    insert(head,1);
    insert(head,2);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Inside function **insert**,if I pass **head** to the point **node**,and use **node = new ListNode(value);**,the insert action fail and **head** is still NULL.But I use 
**new** allocate memory to **head** directly,it works.I am confused about the point reference inside function in C++ and hope somebody help me figure it out.

Comment: Is there a reason you are implementing a data structure using a C style of programming with struct and global functions rather than using a C++ style with classes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The ListNode constructor and use of `operator new` isn't deep enough down the C++ corridor for you? At least he's using an initializer list, which is more than most do when first starting out.

Comment: @WhozCraig A `List` class would obviate the need to pass the `head` pointer to each function making each function signature a little less complex. It would also remove the problem seen here since `head` would most likely be a member field.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I concur with he nicety of the list class, though it obviates nothing special, as you're replacing `func(objref,...)` with `obj.func(...)` . It would, however, definitely make access to the head pointer considerably simpler for obvious reasons. On that I couldn't agree more. The OP just isn't there (yet). Hopefully soon.

Comment: @OP.. I believe you're trying to do: http://ideone.com/kw9tWk  Changing "head" through a reference to a pointer. But I don't understand why you would want to do that.

Comment: ... or the [*very* short version](http://pastebin.com/RLrihuC0), but honestly, if you're doing this *forward-chaining* your data input will me *much* more efficient.

Comment: thanks,I learn a lot from your answers.I am doing some exercise in leetcode and want to create list to debug my code.@Brandon I create   **node** and implement **node = new ListNode(value)** in order to make the sentence and variable in **if** and **else** looks uniform.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
ptr = new whatever;
```

allocates memory, maybe calls a constructor, and *assigns a new value to `ptr`.*

Now consider these two functions:

```
void foo1(int &n)
{
  int k=n;
  k=5;
}

void foo2(int &n)
{
  n=5;
}
```

After I call `foo1`, the value of the variable I passed (by reference) is unchanged. But after I call `foo2`, it is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Find my inline comments to understand what each step is doing

```
node = head; //! Here your node pointer pointing to the memory pointed by head
if(!node) //! You are checking if that memory is null or not
{
    node = new ListNode(value); //! now you are pointing your node pointer to some newly allocated memory, there is no impact on head pointer.
    //! If you want to change the head pointer also so
    head = node; //! Now head also pointing to the newly allocated location.
}
```

Comment: Thanks，I have realized that if I don't implement **head=node** at last,**node** stores new memory address not **NULL** any more,and **head** still stores **NULL** and will not change.